# Angular remote server web service authorization

Tags: javascript, angularjs, wso2-api-manager

I'm trying to get data from remote web service with my angular app. Since server uses WSO2 api manager to handle requests I need  to pass "Authorization: Bearer 31363a37a017a4b2e9b1104981ff" along with requests.

My request looks follows

```js
movieControllers.controller('MovieListCtrl', ['$scope', '$http',
  function($scope, $http) {
    $http.jsonp('http:myserverurl/1.0.0'
      ,{
    headers: {Authorization: 'Bearer AUTH_CODE_HERE'}
  }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      $scope.movies= data;
      $scope.status = status;
 
    }).error(function(error, status, headers, config) {
      $scope.status = status;
     
});

   }]);
```

But it gives me "unauthorized access". It seems header is not set correctly.
Then I did direct request to my api. It not required any authorization. And it work fine.

I'm new to angular and this API and web service thing. Do I need to install extra module for Oauth ? (I guess this authorization thing is oauth. correct me if I'm wrong). can anyone point me in to right direction and it's highly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: You can make sure that header is set or not in header request. I would recommend you to create a Interceptor for type of stuff. Let know if you are able to see request header in chrome.

Comment: No header is not setting correctly. I can't see header in request.

Answer (score 0):

Before `$http.jsonp` if you assign Authorization. it will work

```
$http.defaults.headers.common. Authorization = 'Bearer AUTH_CODE_HERE'
```

In this case your code should be -

```
movieControllers.controller('MovieListCtrl', ['$scope', '$http',
  function($scope, $http) {

    $http.defaults.headers.common. Authorization = 'Bearer AUTH_CODE_HERE';

    $http.jsonp('http:myserverurl/1.0.0')
    .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    $scope.movies= data;
    $scope.status = status;

    }).error(function(error, status, headers, config) {
    $scope.status = status;

   });
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would also recommend creating interceptor, because interceptor act as request builder here.

All you have to do is mention interceptor in $httpProvider

```
 var myApp = angular.module('myApp');
 //Set configs
 myApp.config(function($httpProvider){
   //Add dependencyof interceptor  
   $httpProvider.interceptors.push( 'myInterceptor');
 });
```

Now create an interceptor in factory

```
 //Create you interceptor here
 mayApp.factory('myInterceptor', function() {
       return {
          request: function(config) {              
            config.headers[ 'Authorization' ] = 'Bearer AUTH_CODE_HERE';
            return config;
          }
       }
  });
```

This way, you solve adding authorization header in each request. This interceptor will also be useful if you want to change configs or wants to generate authorization header dynamically for each request. Hope this helps to you. Cheers!